# Java - poi : issue while appending one docx to another : Use of undefined namespace > prefix: w15

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am getting this exception while appending a docx to another docx.

> org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Use of undefined namespace
> prefix: w15   at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3499)
> at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parse(Locale.java:713)     at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:697)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:684)
> at
> org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:208)
> at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:80)

```
private static void appendBody(CTBody src, CTBody append) throws Exception {
        XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
        optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
        String appendString = append.xmlText(optionsOuter);
        String srcString = src.xmlText();
        String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
        String mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
        String suffix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
        String addPart = appendString.substring(appendString.indexOf(">") + 1, appendString.lastIndexOf("<"));
        CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
        src.set(makeBody);
    }
```

The exception occurs while running :

```
CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
```

Something wrong with one of the docx files?

Comment: The current problem is that your `CTBody append` contains an element from `w15` namespace. But this namespace is not referred in `String prefix` which was got from `CTBody src`. This is because `CTBody src` does **not** contain an element from `w15` namespace.  But this is only **one** problem out of possibly hundreds which occur when someone simply handles `XML` as strings and tries put together `XML` using string methods. That cannot work properly.

Comment: ok, thank you, do you know a better method to merge the two docx documents?

Comment: There is not really a good approach for merging `*.docx` documents. That's why I always try avoiding that. Only merging together the `XML` of  the document bodys would be possible with some effort. But the bodys might contain references to other document parts (pictures, comments, headers, footers, ...). And then it becomes ugly because those are referenced by Ids which must be unique in the same document. And of course the other parts also need to be merged then.